# Change pixels transparent background

Tags: python, image

I have several different images in which I want to change every transparent pixel of the image into a different color.

I've found a way to extract all the RGB values of the transparent pixels of an image as such:

```
data[data[:,:,3]==0,:3][0]
```

Now when I try to assign a different array to this pixel it doesn't work:

```
data[data[:,:,3]==0,:3][0] = np.array([255,0,255])

print(data[data[:,:,3]==0,:3][0])
Out[1]: [0 0 0]
```

How do I change this pixel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

I see from your comment that you need more flexibility than I understood from your question. Try this:

```
In [85]: im = np.array(Image.open('image.png').convert('RGBA'))

In [86]: for x in np.argwhere(im[:,:,3]==0):
    ...:     im[x[0],x[1],:]=np.random.randint(0,255), np.random.randint(0,255), np.random.randint(0,255), np.random.randint(0,255)
```

**Original Answer**

I think you mean this:

```
In [32]: im = np.array(Image.open('image.png').convert('RGBA'))

In [33]: im
Out[33]: 
array([[[126, 126, 126, 255],        <--- grey pixel
        [126, 126, 126, 255],
        [126, 126, 126, 255],
        [126, 126, 126, 255],
        [126, 126, 126, 255]],

       [[126, 126, 126, 255],
        [255,   0,   0,   0],        <--- transparent pixel
        [255,   0,   0,   0],        <--- transparent pixel
        [255,   0,   0,   0],        <--- transparent pixel
        [126, 126, 126, 255]],

       [[126, 126, 126, 255],
        [126, 126, 126, 255],
        [126, 126, 126, 255],
        [126, 126, 126, 255],
        [126, 126, 126, 255]]], dtype=uint8)

In [34]: im[im[:,:,3]==0]=(1,2,3,4)

In [35]: im
Out[35]: 
array([[[126, 126, 126, 255],
        [126, 126, 126, 255],
        [126, 126, 126, 255],
        [126, 126, 126, 255],
        [126, 126, 126, 255]],

       [[126, 126, 126, 255],
        [  1,   2,   3,   4],
        [  1,   2,   3,   4],
        [  1,   2,   3,   4],
        [126, 126, 126, 255]],

       [[126, 126, 126, 255],
        [126, 126, 126, 255],
        [126, 126, 126, 255],
        [126, 126, 126, 255],
        [126, 126, 126, 255]]], dtype=uint8)
```

**Sample image**:

It's a row of three transparent red pixels surrounded by an opaque grey border one pixel wide. It's quite small...

[image]

Comment: This is closely related to what I'm looking for but not quite. In your example, how would I adjust the RGBA values of each pixel seperately? Thus, instead of changing *all* transparant pixels to (1,2,3,4), how could I make it so that the first has e.g. (1,2,3,4), the second has e.g. (5,6,7,8), etc... Thanks for your reply regardless!

Comment: I have updated the code to be more flexible than I understood from your original question.

Comment: I'm sorry the question wasn't too clear. Sometimes it's hard to describe via words what exactly you're looking for. I accepted your answer though as it seems more optimized than my solution. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Cool - glad it helped. Good luck with your project!

Answer (score 2):

While a vectorized operation might be available for what I was trying to achieve, the solution I've found to work goes as follows.

```
for h in range(0,data.shape[0]):
    for w in range(0,data.shape[1]):
        if data[h, w][3] == 0:
            data[h, w] = np.random.randint(0,255), np.random.randint(0,255), np.random.randint(0,255), 255
```

This goes over every pixel in the image, then checks whether that pixel is transparant or not and if it is it randomizes the RGB values of that pixel. Might be rather slow but works as intended!